# How do I extract a list from numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I got the following numpy array:

```
array(["['life', 'illusion', 'researcher', 'prove', 'reality', 'doesnt', 'exist', 'youre', 'looking', 'life', 'illusion', 'least', 'quantum', 'level', 'theory', 'recently', 'confirmed', 'set', 'researcher', 'finally', 'mean', 'test', 'john', 'wheeler’s', 'delayedchoice', 'theory', 'concluded', 'physicist', 'right', '1978', 'mr', 'wheeler’s', 'proposed', 'experiment', 'involved', 'moving', 'object', 'given', 'choice', 'act', 'like', 'wave', 'particle', 'former', 'acting', 'vibration', 'frequency', 'distinguish', 'wave', 'latter', 'frequency', 'determine', 'position', 'space', 'unlike', 'wave', 'point', '‘decide’', 'act', 'like', 'one', 'time', 'technology', 'available', 'conduct', 'strong', 'experiment', 'scientist', 'able', 'carry']"])
```

and was wondering if anyone knows how to get the list of strings from there, eg. `['life', 'illusion', 'researcher',...]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure why you have this string saved as a `np.array`, but you could just use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = np.array(["['life', 'illusion', 'researcher', 'prove', 'reality..."])

literal_eval(a[0])
# ['life', 'illusion', 'researcher', 'prove', 'reality', 'doesnt...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer @yatu

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string and then strip any extraneous characters:

```
x = np.array(["['life', 'illusion', 'researcher', 'prove', 'reality', 'doesnt', 'exist', 'youre', 'looking', 'life', 'illusion', 'least', 'quantum', 'level', 'theory', 'recently', 'confirmed', 'set', 'researcher', 'finally', 'mean', 'test', 'john', 'wheeler’s', 'delayedchoice', 'theory', 'concluded', 'physicist', 'right', '1978', 'mr', 'wheeler’s', 'proposed', 'experiment', 'involved', 'moving', 'object', 'given', 'choice', 'act', 'like', 'wave', 'particle', 'former', 'acting', 'vibration', 'frequency', 'distinguish', 'wave', 'latter', 'frequency', 'determine', 'position', 'space', 'unlike', 'wave', 'point', '‘decide’', 'act', 'like', 'one', 'time', 'technology', 'available', 'conduct', 'strong', 'experiment', 'scientist', 'able', 'carry']"])

[x.strip("[]'',") for x in x[0].split()]
```